# reading xlsx with multi sheets into lists c#

Tags: c#, excel, list, csv, xlsx

I have a code where i read a file (`.csv`) and store its columns in lists.

```
var pathskill = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString(), "skill.csv");

using (var fs1 = File.OpenRead(pathskill))
using (var reader1 = new StreamReader(fs1))

while (!reader1.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = reader1.ReadLine();
    var values = line.Split(',');

    list_MainId.Add(Convert.ToDouble(values[0]));
    list_MainName.Add(values[1]);
    list_AmountMade.Add(Convert.ToInt32(values[2]));
    list_Level.Add(Convert.ToDouble(values[3]));
    list_Exp.Add(Convert.ToDouble(values[4]));
    list_MadeFrom_One_Id.Add(Convert.ToDouble(values[5]));
    list_Amount_MadeFrom_One.Add(Convert.ToInt32(values[6]));
    list_MadeFrom_Two_Id.Add(Convert.ToDouble(values[7]));
    list_Amount_MadeFrom_Two.Add(Convert.ToInt32(values[8]));

}
```

This code works great and i get 9 lists with values.

However, i have many `.csv` files and i think it will be better that each will be like a sheet in xlsx file and i can choose which one to read by its name.

For example to have a sheet called `skill1`, `skill2` and so on.

Is there a way to read a specific sheet from xlsx by its name and store it columns into lists?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this. You could unzip xlsx files and read sheet XMLs directly, or you may use some library that can work with xlsx (e.g. EPPLUS that is freeware).